# Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

When I deploy my SLS project, I get the following error:

> Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's
>   installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless
>   config file

But I did install the plugin `serverless-offline` correctly, please can someone help me fix it.

Here is my `serverless.yml` file:

```
   service: email-sender

    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs4.3

    functions:
      send:
        handler: handler.send
        events:
          - http:
              path: submissions
              method: post
              response:
                headers:
                  Content-Type: "text/json"
              cors:
                origins:
                  - '*'
    package:
      exclude:
        - node_modules/**
      include:
        - node_modules/serverless-offline/**

    plugins:
      - serverless-offline
```

Comment: Why are you excluding `node_modules/**`? Your lambda functions will need your dependencies to run.

Comment: @Quentin Hayot thank you did not noltice

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Answer (score 8):

Serverless offline is a plugin to run only on your development machine, not in production.

To enable it add the following to `serverless.yml`:

```
    plugins:
      - serverless-offline
```

and remove the following lines

```
      include:
        - node_modules/serverless-offline/**
```

also check your `package.json` and make sure it is a `devDependencies`.

Comment: Unless you include node-modules/serverless-offline in the package the deploy fails, if you have the plugin listed.

Answer (score 6):

Please ensure that serverless-offline package is included in dev dependencies, if not then  add it

> "serverless-offline": "3.20.2"

and run,

```
npm install --save-dev
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this error while running an automated CI pipeline or locally, try the following:

```
- npm config set prefix /usr/local
- npm install -g serverless
- npm install serverless-offline -g
- npm install --save-dev
- serverless deploy --stage production --verbose
```

Also, check your **package.json** and ensure the **serverless-offline** package is included in **devDependencies**.

This fixed the issue for me.

*Happy Serverless!*

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue on bitbucket pipelines. I fixed the issue (after many trials and errors) by updating "script" section of your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file with the following:

```
          script:
            - npm install -g npm
            - npm install --save-dev
            - pipe: atlassian/serverless-deploy:1.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $KEY_DEFINED_ON_BITBUCKET
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $KEY_DEFINED_ON_BITBUCKET
```

Also, check your `package.json` and ensure the `serverless-offline` package and any other plugins in the `serverless.yml` file are included in **devDependencies**.

Big thanks to [K Manoj Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302742/serverless-plugin-serverless-offline-not-found-make-sure-its-installed-and-l/58452534#58452534) for giving me a clue.

If you are not using bitbucket pipeline, I feel replacing the "pipe" section  on the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file with something like `npm run deploy` and adding `"deploy": "serverless deploy"` to the "scripts" section on your `package.json` will work.

Answer (score 1):

The error is resolved by installing the package

```
npm install serverless-offline -g
```

If the serverless package is not added, do add that:

```
npm i -g serverless
```

The terminal commands and the console logs shown below:

```
keerthipriyagkurtakoti@Keerthipriyas-MacBook-Pro aws-node-express-api % npm start                          

> aws-node-express-api@1.0.0 start /Users/keerthipriyagkurtakoti/Desktop/krishnaWorkspace/Educative/educative/aws-node-express-api
> nodemon --exec serverless offline

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `serverless offline`
Environment: darwin, node 14.16.1, framework 3.21.0, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file. Run "serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline" to install it.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
^C%                                                                                                                                            keerthipriyagkurtakoti@Keerthipriyas-MacBook-Pro aws-node-express-api % npm install serverless-offline -g
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN serverless-offline@8.8.1 requires a peer of serverless@^1.60.0 || 2 || 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ serverless-offline@8.8.1
added 192 packages from 267 contributors in 34.928s
keerthipriyagkurtakoti@Keerthipriyas-MacBook-Pro aws-node-express-api % npm start                        

> aws-node-express-api@1.0.0 start /Users/keerthipriyagkurtakoti/Desktop/krishnaWorkspace/Educative/educative/aws-node-express-api
> nodemon --exec serverless offline

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `serverless offline`

Starting Offline at stage dev (us-east-1)

Offline [http for lambda] listening on http://localhost:3002
Function names exposed for local invocation by aws-sdk:
           * user: aws-node-express-api-dev-user
           * test: aws-node-express-api-dev-test
           * authentication: aws-node-express-api-dev-authentication
           * postFeed: aws-node-express-api-dev-postFeed

   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                                                  │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/dev/user/{any*}                                    │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/user/invocations             │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/dev/test/{any*}                                    │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/test/invocations             │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/dev/auth/{any*}                                    │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/authentication/invocations   │
   │   ANY | http://localhost:4000/dev/social/{any*}                                  │
   │   POST | http://localhost:4000/2015-03-31/functions/postFeed/invocations         │
   │                                                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Server ready: http://localhost:4000 

Enter "rp" to replay the last request
```

Error is shown in the picture below
[image]

The error being addressed
in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error as I had the NODE_ENV set to "production" in my local dev environment.

serverless-offline does not work with this I believe. So set NODE_ENV to "development" or something that's not "production"