# Serverless - offline plugin

Tags: node.js, serverless, serverless-offline

I have a project in Node16 where I am trying to use Serverless-offline plugin. But I do not know how to make it work.

This is how I set up the plugin in the serverless.yml file:

[image: Serverles.yml plugin section]

And these are the ways I tried to run to install the plugin:

`npm install serverless-offline --save-dev`

`serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline`

However, every time I try to run sls offline start I get the same error:

[image]

```
 $ sls offline start    
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Environment: darwin, node 12.13.1, framework 3.22.0 (local) 3.22.0v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file. Run "serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline" to install it.
```

Also, if I run a `npm list -g` I can see the plugin is installed:

[image]

What's going on? What am I missing? This is the gitHub url https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/NursertApp/tree/main/children-api

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/q/46302742/13779320 solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The command is `sls offline`

You can check this [link](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline) to know more details about it.

Comment: Upvote if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but you can run `sls offline` or `serverless offline` as it says in the documentation.

Comment: @EstefaniaCastroVizoso you ran `sls offline start` start is not present according to your question that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Msvstl, but I have also tried those options, `sls offline start`, `Serverless offline start`, the result is always the same error ...

**Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins" section of your serverless config file. Run "serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline" to install it.**

Comment: @EstefaniaCastroVizoso is your issue resolved or not? did you try installing the plugin globally -g?

Comment: No, it is not resolved at all! And yes, I have tried all the things mentioned above

Comment: @EstefaniaCastroVizoso can you run `sls offline` command and add error logs instead of images in the question.

Comment: Yes, I can (it is done), but the error is the one you see above. I don't know how to see more logs when I run that command. It is all I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248230/discussion-between-estefania-castro-vizoso-and-msvstl).

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, the problem was the node version (I was using node 12). After updating it (brew upgrade node) to node 18, the `sls offline` command worked as a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the below plugin on root folder

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved, the problem was the node version. Here it is the repo with the example https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/NurseryApp